# Directive's shared scope through the $compile method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some trouble with isolating scope between directives.  I am thinking that it might have to do with the way I'm using the `$compile` method in my directive defined in the `$scope.addCategory` method.

Here is my directive:

```
directive('siteCategory', [ function(){
        return{
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'site-category.html',
            scope:{},
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$compile', function( $scope, $element, $attrs, $compile ){
                $scope.view = {};
                $scope.view.defaultCategoryName = "Name of Category";
                $scope.view.displayName = true;
                $scope.data = {};
                
                $scope.removeCategory = function(){
                    console.log('removing category', $element);
                    $element.remove();
                };
                $scope.addCategory = function(){
                    var newCategory = angular.element( document.createElement( 'site-category' ) );
                    
                    console.log('adding category', $element);
                    
                    angular.element( $element[0].querySelector('.category-name') ).after( newCategory );
                    $compile( $element )( $scope );
                    $scope.$apply();
                };
                
                $scope.updateCategoryName = function(){
                    console.log('editing category name', $element);
                    $scope.view.displayName = false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                    $element[0].querySelector('.category-name > input').focus();
                };
                
                $scope.saveCategoryName = function(){
                    
                    $scope.data.categoryName = $scope.data.categoryName.trim();
                    console.log('saving category name: ', $scope.data.categoryName);
                    
                    if( $scope.data.categoryName === "" ){
                        $scope.data.categoryName = $scope.view.defaultCategoryName;
                    }
                    $scope.view.displayName = true;
                    $scope.$apply();
                };
                
            }],
            
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                
                angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.remove')).bind( 'click', scope.removeCategory );
                angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.add')).bind( 'click', scope.addCategory );
                angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.display-name')).bind( 'click', scope.updateCategoryName );               
                angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.category-name input')).bind( 'blur', scope.saveCategoryName );
                
                // Default category name
                scope.data.categoryName = scope.view.defaultCategoryName;
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Here is the template for the directive:

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="icon remove" data-icon="&#xe01e;"></span>
        <span class="icon add" data-icon="&#xe01d;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="category-name">
        <span ng-show="view.displayName" class="display-name">{{data.categoryName}}</span>
        <input ng-hide="view.displayName" type='text' ng-model='data.categoryName' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the stylized layout of the directive:
[image: directive layout]

When clicking on the category title, I change the text to an input box:
[image]

Problems start to rise when I add more "subcategories" to the parent category. I click on the parent text and the input box shows for both the parent and the first subcategory created:
[image]

Same type of behavior happens when subcategories have further subcategories themselves:
[image]

When clicking on the "add" icon, a new subcategory is created relative to the parent.  This action is happening in the `$scope.addCategory` method in the directive.  It changes the markup to have the follow *before* the $compile method is ran:

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="icon remove" data-icon="&#xe01e;"></span>
        <span class="icon add" data-icon="&#xe01d;"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="category-name">
        <span ng-show="view.displayName" class="display-name">{{data.categoryName}}</span>
        <input ng-hide="view.displayName" type='text' ng-model='data.categoryName' />
    </div>
    <site-category></site-category> <!-- new directive is created and will be compiled -->
</div>
```

Thanks to those that have made it this far, so it seems that the scope on the `$scope.view` object and on the `$scope.data` object are being shared between parent-child relationships.  Hoping to have each directive have an isolated scope.

jsfiddle of the semi-styled code found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tqxqb/1/

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
 scope: {},
```

with

> scope:'isolate',

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tqxqb/2/

Comment: you can also refer to "Directive Definition Object" at:  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive